# How can I generate dashboard report with URL i.e. navigated to by my Selenium Script in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am executing my selenium script using **Selenium/WebDriver sampler** and after the execution of multiple threads, it has been only showing the overall results for each user. But I want to know the particular time taken by a particular URL that is moving from one to another mapping that I have written in my Selenium Script. Currently, it is showing like this :

[image]

> *My Jmeter test Plan:*

[image]

**My requirement is to get each URL report as well for the particular Agent which we are navigated with the help Selenium Script.** *How can I do like in this way? Can anyone please help me that I have already done a lot of R&D to get this but didn't get any solution for this.*

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get the current URL using [`WDS.browser.getCurrentUrl()` function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getCurrentUrl--)
2. You can set the desired Sampler title using [`WDS.sampleResult.setSampleLabel()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSampleLabel-java.lang.String-)
3. You can access JMeter Variables using [WDS.vars](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) shorthand

Assuming all above you can dynamically build the names for your Samplers using the following expression:

```
WDS.sampleResult.setSampleLabel('Agent: ' + WDS.vars.get('USERNAME') + ' :: Customer: ' + WDS.vars.get('MSISDN') + ' :: URL: ' + WDS.browser.getCurrentUrl())
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: So for achieve different URL requests after every click, What should I have to do? Should I have to use the different selenium web driver samplers for every click?

Comment: Whenever you call this function it will update the current WebDriver Sampler with the current browser's URL, if you need to save each url - you need to use a separate Sampler for each action

Comment: Yes, I want a result like Http requests where we get all the results according to the URL. Now I think I should achieve as you said above to use the separate sampler for each action.